# php connection error with mongo replica set

Tags: php, mongodb, amazon-ec2, php-mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

I have 3 instances on EC2, each with elastic IP, and each running mongo version 3.2. All are in the replica set by the type name. The bind_ip settings in mongod.conf are configured with the IP 0.0.0.0.

I'm trying to connect mongo through php. I already have installed the extension [mongodb](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php) and [library](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-library/).

All of which are on the same port, and the primary IP: 52.67.34.1

My connection:

```
$this->manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager(
            "mongodb://52.67.34.1,52.67.77.2,52.67.30.3/?replicaSet=homologation");
```

But to do query or insert, it gives the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoDB \ Driver \ Exception \ ConnectionTimeoutException' with message 'No suitable servers found (`serverselectiontryonce` set): [connection error calling ismaster on '52.67.34.1:27017'] [connection error calling ismaster on '52.67.77.2:27017'] [connection error calling ismaster on '52.67.30.3:27017'] [Failed connecting to '172.31.1.1:27017': Connection timed out] [Failed connecting to '172.31.2.2:27017': Connection timed out] [Failed connecting to '172.31.3.3:27017': Connection timed out]

How do I fix this error? Connect to mongo?

Comment: Have you checked the connectivity b/w app server and mongodb servers?

Comment: Is this port 27017 open in your security group

Comment: @Astro One ip works, more than one does not work

Comment: @error2007s The port is open in security group

Comment: Have you checked the status of the replica set? cf https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.status/

Answer (score 1):

I had issues connecting to replica set in PHP with the machine IPs, and solved this using the machine hosts.

If you don't have your server hosts in your DNS (public or private), I would suggest to declare each replica member in the /etc/hosts file.

It worked for me, and I hope it'll help.